# C# - Prevent duplicate retrieval of posts

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

i'm rather new and am trying to create a C# program that retrieves post from Facebook using FB API.

I have a word count feature which checks against a negative word dictionary.
This means that it would display the negative word along with its frequency occurrence.

The problem i'm facing now is that, i want to display the posts that contains this negative words. However, if the negative word exists 3 times in the post, the post would appear thrice. How do i solve this problem?

```
Below is my code:

(For designer)

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

    namespace empTRUST
    {
        public partial class PostAnalysis : Form
        {
            DBStatusDL ad;
            string target_fbid;
            public PostAnalysis(string target_fbid)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.target_fbid = target_fbid;
                ad = new DBStatusDL();

            }

            private void button_Displayposts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int i = 1;
                var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\Dictionary"); //Load the dictionary from debug folder
                var ed = new matchingWordsWithPosts();
                var rows = ad.LoadStatus(target_fbid); //Call the load status function based on fb_id
                foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles()) //For loop, to loop through files
                {
                    var dict = File.ReadAllLines(dir.FullName + "\\" + file);
                    foreach (var row in rows)
                    {
                        List<DataRow> words = ed.countWordsInStatus(row, dict); // Retrieves word dictionary returned from function

                        foreach (var word in words)
                        {
                            var item = new ListViewItem(new[] { i.ToString() ,word["Status_message"].ToString(), word["Status_time"].ToString() });
                            listViewPosts.Items.Add(item);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            private void button_Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
                var abc = new AnalysisPage(target_fbid);
                abc.Show();
            }
        }
    }

(For class)

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Data;

    namespace empTRUST
    {
        class matchingWordsWithPosts
        {
            public List<DataRow> countWordsInStatus(DataRow status, string[] dictArray)
            {
                List<DataRow> statusList = new List<DataRow>();
                var words = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); // local word dictionary is created here
                foreach (var dictEntry in dictArray)
                {
                    var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
                    string smallDictEntry = dictEntry.ToLower();
                    foreach (Match match in wordPattern.Matches(status["Status_message"].ToString()))
                    {
                        if (match.ToString() == smallDictEntry)
                        {
                            statusList.Add(status);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return statusList;   // returns local word dictionary to receiving end
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide the `countWordsInStatus()` function, I can't know if that's the problem. However, it *looks* like the problem is that that function continues going through a post even if it has already matched one such word. To fix this, you could put `continue;` (or perhaps a `break;`, depending on the code you're using) after adding a post to the list you're returning. This would have the loop skip to the next post, and make sure it doesn't continue counting words in the post that has already had a match.

If you post that function, it should be much easier to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a word is matched and you process the post exit the loop.